# Index of data file in title

Tags: indexing, gnuplot, sprint

I have a Gnuplot data file broken into sections (2 blank lines). I wish to capture the indices I've selected to plot into the key of the plot, "plot 'datafile' index 5:10:1 us 7:8 ti XXX", where XXX is the index. I understand the the pseudocolumn, column(-2), contains the index value.

How do I capture the index and 'sprint' it into the title? The index is, of course, and integer.

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? If yes, then please accept one of the answers, indicating that your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to see as XXX? The index? Do you actually mean the indices from 5 to 10 as several key entries? As far as I know the title is only evaluated once per plot command. Hence, you have to put the plot command into a for loop.

**Script:**

```
### plotting several blocks with index as title
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 10
    do for [i=1:12] {
        plot '+' u 1:(i+rand(0)) w table, \
             '+' u ("") every ::::1 w table   # two empty lines
    }
unset table

set key out

plot for [i=5:10] $Data u 1:2 index i w l ti sprintf("index %d",i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I was frustrated when using 'index 1:10 ' that I would get the last index value.

Comment: @DonalDay glad to hear! On StackOverflow: helpful=upvote, "solved the problem"=accept!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relevant plot from the on-line demo collection:
[plot #2 of 'iterate.dem'](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.5/iterate.html)
The plot command that generated it is

```
splot for [i=1:*] "whale.dat" index i title sprintf("scan %d",i) with lines
```

If you do not want to extract all the available data segments you can adjust the iteration limits to match which set of index values you want to select.
[image]